# What does it mean to [not] have vsnprintf, _vsnprintf

Tags: c++, msvcrt

And should I have the same setting in all `config.h` files in the project?

Symptom: `nmake` attempting to build parts of the project at the MSVC 'Command Prompt' is throwing `inconsistent dll linkage vsnprintf`. Googling for that message says it's usually to do with macros not working consistently. I'm building a package that presumably works; I haven't changed the distro.

Those two Microsoft routines documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l?view=vs-2019). There's flags in the `config.h` files

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the `vsnprintf' function. */
/* #undef HAVE_VSNPRINTF */
...
/* Define to 1 if you have the `_vsnprintf' function. */
#define HAVE__VSNPRINTF 1
```

Some but not all `config.h` files are generated from [`config.h.in`](https://github.com/FranklinChen/hugs98-plus-Sep2006/blob/master/docs/building/win32.txt)/`configure.ac` at package install. I seem to have different settings for `HAVE_VSNPRINTF` in different `config.h`s in different subtrees of the project. I don't want to override the distro, but that doesn't seem right(?)

`vsnprintf` is in `MSVCRnnn.DLL` where `nnn` is the MSVC release; I've installed v12.0/Update 5 Community. Why such an old version? ...

**Background**

I'm trying to build an ancient version of the Haskell Hugs compiler, September 2006. This is mostly written for Unix environments in C/C++. But I'm building on Windows 8.1, x64-based processor. The instructions I'm following are [here](https://github.com/FranklinChen/hugs98-plus-Sep2006/blob/master/docs/building/win32.txt); and that repo holds the whole directory structure I'm building (thank you Franklin Chen).

The Unix-oriented part I have built, using MinGW/MSYS, not Cygwin. (64-bit MinGW did not go well, so I reverted and used 32-bit.)

Now I'm trying to build the Windows part, which is essentially a GUI veneer over the Unix -- starting at 'Using Microsoft Visual C++' in the instructions. Visual Studio was not at all happy: the project files are `.vcproj`, no longer supported. I tried `devenv /Upgrade` to get them as `.vcxproj`. But then further problems trying `MSBuild` that it couldn't validate against an `.xsd`; either `Microsoft.Build.{Core|Common}.xsd` gave many rejections about missing types. So I've abandoned that approach.

So I'm at the instructions 'Driving Microsoft Visual C++ from the Command Line', using the MSVC-supplied `.bat` file to fire up the command line, [as doco'd here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019#developer_command_prompt_shortcuts). `nmake` is running but throwing heaps of `inconsistent dll` warnings, for `vsnprintf` only. I'm also getting `differs in parameter lists` for various routines; is that a knock-on error? Eventually `nmake` crashes out, without building the `.exe`s I want.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using MSYS2 rather than MSYS , it is better all round. You can install 32bit or 64-bit build and targets.

Comment: I first tried MSYS2; the build routines kept barfing because MSYS2 defined environment variables Hugs hadn't heard of in 2006. (That's why I reverted to 32-bit.) My machine's Unix environment is only for building this app.

Comment: MSYS2 comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions. There's no "revert to 32-bit" if you are using MSYS2 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the configure scripts is to figure out whether **your compiler** has `vsnprintf`. Of course various generated `config.h` files get different results, that is the entire point. If they all had `vsprintf`, there would be no need to check!

Having said that, I'd describe the `configure.ac` mechanism as positively ancient. On more than one occasion, I've found it easier to just create a new `.vcxproj` from scratch.

I'm not sure about the MSDN documentation you're linking. You link to the VC14.x documentation, which notes that `vsnprintf` has changed since VC12.0, which you claim to use.

Comment: Thanks but sorry I don't understand: my compiler or my machine? If `vsnprintf` is on the _machine_ shouldn't all compilers use it? Especially if they're building the one app. I assumed `config.h` is to cope with compiling on different machines. Anyway: the `make` that works has `HAVE_VSNPRINTF 1`; the `nmake` that doesn't work has `HAVE_VSNPRINTF` not defined.

Comment: I linked the 2019 docos because that's all that's available on Microsoft's site. Thanks for the tip re the version change, just as well I installed VC12.0.

Comment: @AntC: `vsnprintf` is part of the Universal CRT and it's on every Windows 10 machines, but you specifically mention using Windows 8.1. The "compiling on every machine" logic is typical for Unix, but on Windows it's unheard of. The vast majority of Windows PC's do not even have a compiler installed. That's why you have Visual C++ redistributable libraries, and that installer also takes care of the Universal CRT on Win8.1

Comment: BTW the `.vcproj` comes with the distro (dated 2005), `configure.ac` has not touched it.

Comment: @AntC the compiler you are using to compile the project. As of right now, I have 3 different versions of MSVC and it's libraries on the same machine, because the projects I work on don't upgrade tools at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this for this particular application. `#define HAVE_VSNPRINTF 1`, also `#define HAVE_SNPRINTF 1` in `config.h` makes the `inconsistent dll linkage vsnprintf` error go away. That is, I changed those flags to same as in the `configure.ac`-generated `config.h`.

Within the project there's many `config.h` in different subtrees setting those flags. But there's only one file that reads it/takes action on it: `src/machdep.c` "Machine dependent code". That's `#include`d by all applications. This application being essentially written for a Unix platform, I'd expect machine-wide settings.

I take the point in @MSalters' answer that a MSVC platform does not necessarily expect the same settings machine-wide. But this application has the Unix/MSys and MSVC environments tightly bound, so I'd expect they want consistency.

Then I'm making progress. I haven't got the whole application to compile yet: it's got further, so I have more `inconsistent dll linkage ...` errors for other routines. I can see further inconsistencies in flag settings in the `config.h`s.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

The symptom `C4273: 'xxx' inconsistent dll linkage` is a Warning not an Error, so the compiler carries on. `vsnprintf` and friends format a list of arguments to an output buffer. So it probably doesn't matter if different `.exe`s in the project link to different versions. At worst they'll produce different results in the output for the same arguments.

So just ignore the message, and don't worry about discrepancies in the `config.h`.

Full disclosure: after editting the `config.h` to make the `vsnprintf` etc messages go away; I have some residual inconsistencies re `malloc` and `free` -- despite editing the `config.h` for any settings to do with `ALLOC`. Differences in alloc behaviour between different `.exe`s are more alarming.